# Download Debian source files for stable rather than unstable

Tags: debian, apt

I am downloading the Debian source files for the `heimdal` package by running this command

```
apt-get source --download-only heimdal
```

This downloads the source files for the release `sid` (unstable). However, what I want are the sources for release `stretch` (stable). I am running this command on a Debian `jessie` (oldstable) machine. I tried adding the `-t stable` option but that still gave me the source files for unstable.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get source` downloads the newest source it has available by default, but you can override that by specifying a version any of the normal ways:

```
apt-get source --download-only heimdal=7.1.0+dfsg-13+deb9u1
apt-get source --download-only heimdal/stretch
```

should both work, provided you also have stretch deb-src lines in your sources.list.

Another alternative, depending on your workflow, is [dgit](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dgit):

```
dgit clone heimdal stretch,-security
```

will leave you with a git repository in heimdal/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://packages.qa.debian.org/h/heimdal.html

From there you can choose which version you want to download.

In your case, that would be: https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/heimdal

This way, you don't have to mess up your `sources.list`